# Populate a UserForm's ComboBox with column headers, which refer to the column by address

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

This is for a VBA Macro is Excel.
For example, if user selects "ID" from the ComboBox, "A:A" is fed to a procedure for operation, "B:B" for "Name" and so on.
The number of columns and their headers will always be different, and may contain duplicate header names.

I'd appreciate a pointer to the features of VBA I'll need to use.

Comment: can you add a sample file...so that we can get a clear picture of what to workwith

Comment: I can't see where to upload a file. I'm working with spreadsheets that go something like: | ID | Name | Address | Address2 | Email | Phone |

Comment: can you upload it to a drive and share the link

Answer (score 0):

Without more details as to your requirements, this is probably the best I can suggest:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        ComboBox1.AddItem "Column A Text"
        ComboBox1.AddItem "Column B Text"
        ComboBox1.AddItem "Column C Text"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
        Dim rngSelectedColumn As Range
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
          Case "Column A Text"
            Set rngSelectedColumn = Sheet1.Columns(1)
          Case "Column B Text"
            Set rngSelectedColumn = Sheet1.Columns(2)
          Case "Column C Text"
            Set rngSelectedColumn = Sheet1.Columns(3)
        End Select
        Call ProcedureToFeed rngSelectedColumn
    End Sub
```